# custom springboot starters from custom springboot parent are not detected in child projects

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have created a custom springboot parent starter project with couple of custom starters and java projects as modules to maintain the libraries at once place across many microservices I am going to build and installed to maven repository using "mvn install".

Now when I tried to use this custom parent in one of microservices and utilise the functionality available in one of the custom starters microservices unable to detect classes/dependency of custom starter. I was thinking that if I simply inherit from custom parent project I should get all functionalities under that parent, but it's not working. Can someone please guide me on this?

```
project structure -

custom-spring-boot-parent (Maven Parent Project)
  custom-starter-1 (Custom Starter Module)
  custom-starter-2 (Custom Starter Module)
  simple-java-project-1 (Simple Java Project Module)
  simple-java-project-2 (Simple Java Project Module)
pom.xml (Parent POM)
```

**custom springboot parent pom.xml**

```
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>  
  <artifactId>custom-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>  
  <version>1.0.0</version> 
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
           <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>  
           <version>3.1.4</version>  
           <type>pom</type>  
           <scope>import</scope>  
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom-starter-1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>custom-starter-2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Other custom starters as dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<modules>
  <module>custom-starter-1</module>
  <module>custom-starter-2</module>
  <!-- Other custom starter modules -->
</modules>
<!-- Other libraries and plugins -->
```

**microservice pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>custom-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<!-- service specific libraries and plugins -->
```

Now inside this microservice if I try to access classes from **custom-starter-1**, it's not detecting because dependency is not available in classpath. Do I need to add **custom-starter-1** as dependency in this project , which defeats the purpose having common place to maintain dependency.

The plugins and springboot starters from parent pom are available in classpath , only custom starters/jars are not getting loaded in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add relative path to your microservice module

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>custom-spring-boot-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

Comment: relativePath is there in the child pom, missed it in question. I updated the question. As I mentioned in question it's able to utilise all spring-starter libraries and plugins from parent-pom , only custom starters which are built as part of parent-pom are not available in classpath.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051158/spring-boot-custom-starter-cannot-import-custom-starter-class

Comment: This looks like a different issue than the one I mentioned, anyways thanks for helping out. I resolved the issue by adding my custom-starters as dependency in consumer application along with parent